# How to know if a string is a file or folder. and not with path.os.isfile() or path.os.isdir()

Tags: python, dataframe, file, directory, path

I have a python program which lists me the paths which are files and folders stored in cloud in some datalake. I need a way to sort the files from folders. the following is the list of paths

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_01.txt

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_02.txt

I want a way to filter out/ subset of the above to have only files (any kind of files like .txt or .xlsx, .cad, .csv, etc..). In the example above I need

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_01.txt

Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_02.txt

I tried using os.path.isfile() and os.path.isdir(). but the problem is these solutions work when you have the file present in your local path. and the paths what I have is not present in my local environment. Is there any custom logic which I could implement ?  Thanks.

Comment: This cloud and "some datalake" probably have "some" SDK with utils for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using **regex**. The regex pattern looks for **3-4 letter extensions** at the end of each line. 
eg.

```
.xls
.xlsx
.txt
.cad
.csv

...
```

#### Code:

```
import re

path_list = ['Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder',
             'Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2',
             'Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_01.txt',
             'Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_02.txt',
             'Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_03.xlsx']

# Only print the files (not folders)
for item in path_list:
    if re.search(r'\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$', item):
        print(item)
```

#### Output:

```
Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_01.txt
Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_02.txt
Project 1/Example1/SomeFolder/example1.2/example_r_03.xlsx
```